# integrating my mini-server with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have written a mini server that sits on top of IIS and runs on .net 4.0. It  basically uses the `Socket` class to listen for requests and send html to the client using `Socket.Send(byte[])`.What I'm wanting to know is the best way to host this "server" in the .net environment? Do I have to enclose it in an `aspx` page so it loads when the client points to `mysite.index.aspx`? To me this seems pointless because there is no need for the aspx "wrapper". I know about custom modules and have worked out I can do it that way. Ideally what I'd like is to just run my `Server.Run()` method with as little bloat around it as possible. Thoughts?

Comment: Sounds interesting. Like a possible option, you can host it using windows service. Have you considered this way?

Comment: no I haven't. *goes to look into that*